# What's the benefit of using an array of key: value pairs over a single object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

In a few different places I've seen the following being used:

```js
const arr = [
  { key: "someKey", value: 1 },
  { key: "anotherKey", value: true },
  { key: "yetAnotherOne", value: "hello world" },
];
```

To me, it seems more logical to use this structure:

```js
const ob = {
  someKey: 1,
  anotherKey: true,
  yetAnotherOne: "hello world",
};
```

Is there an advantage when using an array like this?

Comment: You should avoid the first array, this si bad code.

Comment: Well, the first form is not necessary "bad code", as it would make it easier to loop over it with `.map(el=>...)` but it is awkward if you need to quickly reference elements using a specific key. The second form can be easily transformed into the first one by using `Object.entries(ob)...`.

Comment: Most of the time you can’t look at a structure in isolation to determine whether it’s “good” or “bad”. You also have to look at how it is processed/used.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are explicitly *ordered*.

Answer (score 0):

An array is typically used for a list of similar objects. Some advantages would be:

- having a selection of array-specific methods to e.g. to filter/sort the objects
- In an array of objects it would be possible to use the same `key`-property multiple times. In an object these would be overwritten.

That's all I could think of. Hope it's helpful ;).

That said I would normally recommend using an object if the above is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it would be better to use the object because it means you can access the value of the property faster and easier using something like `ob.anotherKey` without having to use a loop or having to know the index in the array.

However, this might not always be the case...

Slightly different from the example above:

```
const people = [
  { firstName: "someKey", lastName: 1 },
  { firstName: "anotherKey", lastName: true },
  { firstName: "yetAnotherOne", lastName: "hello world" },
];
```

Is much easier to understand and a better representation of the data and than...

```
const people = {
  someKey: 1,
  anotherKey: true,
  yetAnotherOne: "hello world",
};
```

This also requires previous knowledge that each key is the firstName and each value is the lastName.